# Downloading display driver for HP pavilion g4-1200tu

Tags: hp-pavilion, display-driver

I have a HP Pavilion g4-1200tu Notebook PC running Windows 8.1. But I am not able to download the display driver for it. I tried HP support website but the driver listing page never stops loading. So can anyone have the download link of the intel display driver for my laptop?

Comment: HP is having serious website issues this week, you will have to wait until it gets sorted out.

Comment: You can get the Intel display driver from Intel's website.